# Restrict certain posts from being sent to the feed subscribers

Tags: feed, user-access, content-restriction

Is there any way to restrict certain category’s posts or certain posts from being displayed into site default feed after published? I’m asking this because I don’t want few specific categorie’s posts to be sent to my feedburner subscribers. I think preventing them from displaying into site feed will also prevent them to be sent to the the feed subscribers! What do you think? Or is there any way to do so..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is yes you can. :)

First check out Wordpress's codex here on their RSS feeds. http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds

Then what you can do is change the default head rss links that let browsers know that there is an RSS feed.

In your theme find:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo ('rss2_url');?>" />
```

And replace the `href="<?php bloginfo ('rss2_url'); ?>"` with an alternate rss feed link as explained in the WordPress Codex.

You will want to do it also for the Atom Feed and the regular rss feed as well which are right below the first link i posted above.

Comment: sry 4 late replay. tnx for the tips..